# lazyload: show div only when it's contained image loads

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading, jquery-lazyload

I'm using the [lazyload](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) plugin for loading all the images in my web. These images are each one contained in a div with also some description and buttons.

```
<div class="container">
<h5>blablabla</h5>
<img class='lazy' data-original="http://example.gif" src="">
<form method="post" action='#'>
  <input type="submit" value='add'>
  ...
</form>
</div>

<div class="container">
....
</div>

...
```

It's working but I would like to hide all the div until it's image was fully loaded, unfortunately I couldn't find any hint about how to accomplish it. Is it possible?

**Edit:**
I still couldn't make it work, so I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9aopngmr/2/) hoping you could point me out what's going wrong there. If you comment the `display:none` lazyload work with all the images, otherwise the divs remain always hidden.

[Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/9aopngmr/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the `img` elements hidden by default, and then hook to the `load()` event of the images to show them:

```
.container img { visibility: hidden; }
.container img.show { visibility: visible; }
```

```js
$('.container img').on('load', function() {
    $(this).addClass('show');
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/9aopngmr/3/)

Comment: mmm that's not lazyloading all the div, just the image: https://jsfiddle.net/9aopngmr/5/  (I've added a timeout so we can notice well it)  BTW, you pointed me to the right direction: https://jsfiddle.net/9aopngmr/4/  Please, consider updating the Working example so I can accept your answer.. and thanks a bunch!

Comment: Glad to help. Also, only the images are lazy loading because you've only selected `img.lazy` when initialising the lazyload plugin.

Comment: Please, show me what I should have selected in your example.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do as the concept of lazy loading only applies to images.

Comment: Oh, check the diff between  jsfiddle.net/9aopngmr/5 and jsfiddle.net/9aopngmr/4 I'm showing the div only when the image loads. BTW, I've got it, and thanks to you.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not sure what you're trying to do. I'd suggest you start a new question with a clear statement of what you're trying to do and why this doesn't work.